# "var_dump" functions

Tags: php, debugging, function, server-side

by the function name itself, `var_dump()` dumps everything about a provided parameter EXCEPT the functions of an object.

is there a way of dumping out these functions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot get the object's methods, but you can get the class methods:

```
var_dump(get_class_methods('classname'));
```

or

```
var_dump(get_class_methods(get_class($object)));
```

Comment: Per the PHP docs, you can provide the actual object to `get_class_methods` as of PHP 5.

Answer (score 2):

PHP has a `class_get_methods()` function and a reflection API. Either should suffice.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [ReflectionClass](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionclass.php) API too

An Example:

```
$cls = new ReflectionClass("classname");
var_dump($cls -> getMethods());
```